# Directive does not link from controller($scope) after updating from 1.2.x

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have made a directive that helps me reduce the number of dependencies I need to inject into a main application controller by injecting them into isolated directives.

For instance, I have a drop list of genders `["MALE, "FEMALE"]`. I have registered this array as a value provider. This is a simple example of a directive that functions in `AngularJS 1.2.28`

Directive:

```
module.directive('appGenderOptions', ['genders', function(genders) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.genders = genders;
    },
    compile: function(elem, attr) {
      attr.ngOptions = 'g for g in genders';
    }
  };
}]);
```

View:

```
<select ng-model="person.gender" app-gender-options></select>
```

So when this directive is linked, it adds the genders to the select list and binds to the model without having to inject genders into the main controller.

Having updated to the latest version 1.4.2, the genders are no longer appended to the select list.  I suspect its related to the breaking changes made to the HTML compiler  `$compile` in 1.3 and they way scope isolation now works, but admittedly I am a little stumped.

Could you please provide me some advise as to how I can repair this convenience directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an odd issue and while reviewing the [Migration docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration), I couldn't quite get enough information on what was changed to point out what may have broke your 1.2 example. I'd be interested to find out though, in detail, but as a workaround for your issue, the following should solve it for you...

**Note** that I have injected the `$compile` service as you will see in the example

```
compile: function(elem, attr) {
    elem.removeAttr('app-gender-options'); // necessary to avoid infinite compile loop
    elem.attr('ng-options', 'g for g in genders');
    return function(scope) {
        $compile(elem)(scope);
    };
}
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ojqdm6o5/) - working example

Comment: This is a suitable workaround, thank you. I used to use the compile technique prior to the current implementation - it was preferable as the syntax is cleaner and did not require the second compilation. I'll give it a few more days before resolving the question.

Comment: Hey have you made any progress or found alternative solutions for this yet?

Comment: Hey sorry no, I have not been at work for the last 5 days. Thanks for asking though, I may as well resolve this for now.